# Looking to make an HTML form with and edit field connected to a list

Tags: html, jscript

I would like to preset an HTML page that has list box (scrollable) that is connected to an edit field. Every time the edit field is updated the list box should show only the items that match the text pattern in the edit field.

Am sure it's possible but not even sure what it's called and all my Google attempts have failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this same question, the term that I was looking for was "creating an autocomplete form."